# How to catch SIGTERM in a pod with Minikube

Tags: bash, kubernetes, minikube, termination

I'm using the simplest docker ever:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY script.sh /script.sh
CMD /script.sh
```

Where all the script does is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function sigterm() {
    echo "Got SIGTERM"
    exit
}

trap sigterm SIGTERM

i=1
while true; do
    echo "$(date +%H:%M:%S) | $((i++)) | $HOSTNAME"
    sleep 1
done
```

I'm running this container in Minikube, **but I can't get it to catch any SIGTERM from kubernetes.**

I tried deleting the pod/deployment or to scale it up and down. In no case it got SIGTERM before being deleted. It respects the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` But doesn't seem to run the `preStop` command or send the SIGTERM before killing the pod.

Is that due to using minikube? or am I doing something else wrong?

(the deployment is not part of a service, it's just a deployment)
(SSH into the pod and manually `kill`-ing it works as expected)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading [the Dockerfile documentation on CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

> The CMD instruction has three forms:
>
> - CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
> - CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
> - CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
>
> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute in /bin/sh -c

So you are using the shell form, which means your command is /bin/sh -c script.sh. Then, when kubernetes sends a SIGTERM to the container, is not the script.sh process the one receiving the signal, but the /bin/sh process. That's why you don't see the "Got SIGTERM" message.

When creating a Dockerfile, make sure you use the exec form. Otherwise the application will be started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals. The container’s PID1 will be the shell, your application will not receive any signals.

Try changing your Dockerfile to use the exec form

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY script.sh /script.sh
CMD ["/script.sh"]
```

Comment: Every tiny detail makes such a difference in Docker and Kubernetes. Thanks.